# How to remove comma from list of integers in java

Tags: java

I have a jsp page with dynamically created checkboxes. When we check boxes, a variable takes the corresponding emp id.

For example :  I checked corresponding check boxes of emp id 2 and 4, then I will get an alert box with 2,4.

Now how can I remove the comma and pass values one after the other, since I want to extract the corresponding details of employee in the next jsp. I

I'm looking for the code in Java to remove comma from in between integers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you just want to replace the comma, you do:

```
String newOne = oldString.replaceAll(",","");
```

If you want to get each id in a new integer (which sounds more what you want from the description), you can do:

```
String[] ids = oldString.split(",");
```

you can then loop over the array to get the individual ids:

```
for (String id : ids ) {
   doSomethingWithId(id);
}
```

Comment: newid...[Ljava.lang.String;@1be18e2 i am getting this i have added java.lang.* also how to go about it